# BO(-) example in Weiss Calculus

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, grassmannian, classifying-spaces, stiefel-manifolds

I'nm reading Orthogonal Calculus by Michael Weiss, and trying to understand example 2.7, concerning the derivatives of the functor $BO$, which sends a (finite dimensional) inner product space to the classifying space of its orthogonal group.

My question concerns the homotopy equivalence between the homotopy fiber of the map 
$$
BO(V) \to BO(V\oplus \Bbb{R})
$$
and $O(\Bbb{R} \oplus V)/ O(V)$, and the subsequent homotopy equivalence of this, and the one-point compactificiation of $V$.

By guess for the first one is to use the fact that $BO(V) = Gr(\dim V, \Bbb{R}^\infty)$, where $Gr$ denotes the Grassmannian manifold, and that there is fibre sequence 
$$
O(V) \to Vr(\dim V, \Bbb{R}^\infty) \to Gr(\dim V+1, \Bbb{R}^\infty)
$$
where $Vr$ denotes the Steifel manifold (which is contractible).

Although, I'm not overly sure how this helps.

I'm clueless on the second on currently.

Any references or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the paper in a while, but I think you want

$$F^{(1)}(V)\simeq hofib\left(BO(V)\rightarrow BO(V\oplus\mathbb{R})\right)$$

without the loop functor, rather than with it, since we want $m=0$ in Proposition 2.2. (Here I'm using Weiss's notation of $F(V)=BO(V)$ from the Example 2.7.)

Then the map in the definition of $F^{(1)}$ is just the map induced by the incusion $O(V)\hookrightarrow O(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$ so clearly

$$F^{(1)}(V)\simeq O(V\oplus\mathbb{R})/O(V).$$

Now by definition $O(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the unit sphere $S(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$ of length one vectors in $V\oplus\mathbb{R}$, and the stabiliser of the line $\mathbb{R}$ is exactly $O(V)$. Hence $O(V\oplus\mathbb{R})/O(V)\cong S(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$. Finally applying stereographic projection we get $S(V\oplus\mathbb{R})\cong S^V$ (see, for instance, the nlab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/representation+sphere). Therefore

$$F^{(1)}(V)\simeq S^V$$

as claimed.

Comment: Why is it clear that the homotopy fiber of the map induced by inclusion is $O(V \oplus \Bbb{R})/O(V)$?

Comment: Since we have a fibration sequence $O(V)\hookrightarrow O(V\oplus\mathbb{R})\rightarrow O(V\oplus \mathbb{R})/O(V)$, and the map $BO(V)\rightarrow BO(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$, of which $F^{(1)}$ is the homotopy fibre, is exactly a delooping of the first map in this sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you happen to know of any places where I can read about homotopy fibers of this kind?